# Oracle hospitality OWS

Tags: oracle, soap, postman

I'm trying to send a soap request to opera web services using postman

Here is my request headers screenshot

[image]

and here is my request body screenshot

[image]

according to this [Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufAh3ixgZGk&t=75s) it should work, but I get the below error

[image]

Can you spot the error, explain what does this error means, or have an alternative guide to send the request?

Comment: " it's not working anymore" - what is not working? What is the error?

Comment: the link of the wsdl file

Comment: http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl#Availability

Comment: this is not how SO works.  People are going to click on some random URL.  You need to edit the question and list any error you are getting